# Google OAuth API not working anymore?! 404 error

Tags: windows-phone-7, google-analytics-api, google-oauth

I've got a strange problem with my Analytics Windows Phone App. It's been 2 months now from the first release. My Google Oauth always worked... until several days ago.

It is impossible to authorize the app to access Analytics data anymore. And I've changed totally nothing!

The first URI I use is:

```
 https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?redirect_uri=http:// localhost
 &response_type=code
 &client_id=*myClientAppId*
 &approval_prompt=force
 &scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly
 &access_type=offline
```

It's the same as `https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/`. The Web Explorer shows me the login form, and then the authorization form. When I tap "Authorize access", it redirects me to a 404 page.

I don't know why, it always worked before.

EDIT: OK, this works in Google Chrome. It gives me a 404 at the end but the code is in the browser URI.

EDIT 2: It works in Firefox too! But not in Internet Explorer. Google has modified something that doesn't fit IE! As it is IE in Windows Phone, I'm out of luck.

EDIT 3: This is the URL from Windows Phone IE during the process:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?redirect_uri=http://localhost&response_type=code&client_id=*clientID*&approval_prompt=force&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly&access_type=offline

https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=lso&passive=1209600&continue=https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly&response_type=code&access_type=offline&redirect_uri=http://localhost&approval_prompt=force&client_id=*clientID*&hl=fr-FR&from_login=1&as=-f41460280d51b31&ltmpl=embedded&shdf=Cp8BCxIRdGhpcmRQYXJ0eUxvZ29VcmwaAAwLEhV0aGlyZFBhcnR5RGlzcGxheU5hbWUaGkFuYWx5dGljcyBmb3IgV2luZG93c1Bob25lDAsSBmRvbWFpbhoaQW5hbHl0aWNzIGZvciBXaW5kb3dzUGhvbmUMCxIVdGhpcmRQYXJ0eURpc3BsYXlUeXBlGhJOQVRJVkVfQVBQTElDQVRJT04MEgNsc28iFJZQrUSzSBUX1XVpZxx-K_xFjAA7KAEyFBX1s-5Zjlet_038EBgHpUrtzMWT&scc=1

https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth

http://accounts.google.fr/accounts/SetSID?ssdc=1&sidt=ALWU2cvavauNt1Z0SXgI2DX+i+T5G1snNnu5C+aq/NBExAfG+WenK3WQRLVDLUWqsRcCCbj6c1b1qoZUOQminXYpKJMQzl6FWmuTgA8rVQYtaK5tatpCXffmlXh9CLec/zn8SUijYZILc7vwN9ByicxS1vSyFGvuoteb7wfDiemkcbvaPjfQZ4PrfmEWtl/Us+Gua+ePdTMc9tHFllBYj3TUZDiL7H1FmfPe1nE4jPyteAnGcF500lFyGSYAftGVpsMRQZiJ+4qVhGcgBrFrySpb92sVTq5FGTrQmqryhvhwQF6Sy6SJbq1CqgiavbsZbfwrvZIWVq31&continue=https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?passive=true&go=true&continue=https%253A%252F%252Faccounts.google.com%252Fo%252Foauth2%252Fauth%253Fscope%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.googleapis.com%252Fauth%252Fanalytics.readonly%2526response_type%253Dcode%2526access_type%253Doffline%2526redirect_uri%253Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flhttps://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?passive=true&go=true&continue=https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly&response_type=code&access_type=offline&redirect_uri=http://localhost&approval_prompt=force&client_id=*clientID*&hl=fr-FR&from_login=1&as=-f41460280d51b31&shdf=Cp8BCxIRdGhpcmRQYXJ0eUxvZ29VcmwaAAwLEhV0aGlyZFBhcnR5RGlzcGxheU5hbWUaGkFuYWx5dGljcyBmb3IgV2luZG93c1Bob25lDAsSBmRvbWFpbhoaQW5hbHl0aWNzIGZvciBXaW5kb3dzUGhvbmUMCxIVdGhpcmRQYXJ0eURpc3BsYXlUeXBlGhJOQVRJVkVfQVBQTElDQVRJT04MEgNsc28iFJZQrUSzSBUX1XVpZxx-K_xFjAA7KAEyFBX1s-5Zjlet_038EBgHpUrtzMWT&service=lso&ltmpl=embedded&fss=1

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly&response_type=code&access_type=offline&redirect_uri=http://localhost&approval_prompt=force&client_id=*clientID*&hl=fr-FR&from_login=1&as=-f41460280d51b31&pli=1&auth=DQAAAIMAAAAw6WtQDD3JKEg_qAs6neUVzWA5ixsW0ido7pIOrK5KRLnHA-_QQhVd7RzSelpNhkhCVJxVGSEgQpZINeKa29lwivfu-Rbu-vuM1uR4U-JC3EJZEwDMIMuva19_KNsd83ihmeYcuGbnBvUR5iln1KhZZIvhUkbS9CjVwLRdwbMRG5nRHO-oJruBkuezuntX8Iw

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly&response_type=code&access_type=offline&redirect_uri=http://localhost&approval_prompt=force&client_id=*clientID*&hl=fr-FR&from_login=1&as=-f41460280d51b31&pli=1

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/approval?as=-f41460280d51b31&hl=fr_FR&xsrfsign=APsBz4gAAAAAUHsS0dCApfLAWpZILWjeTNZSt6DUZzug
```

404 error -> `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/`

On Chrome, same URIs, but when I click on "Authorize", I get localhost with the code for the token.

Comment: Thanks for the debugging info. That helps a lot. Also curious what your javascript setting is on your browser. Is js turned off? Maybe the difference is the browser has js turned off. We recently implemented a change that enforces our js requirement, and the enforcement code may be the cause.

Comment: There is no option to deactivate the JS in IE on Windows Phone. There was no recent update of the Windows Phone OS that may be the cause, so I guess something is wrong on the Oauth side. (the last update of WP was one or two months ago)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe in WP, embedded IE webview has javascript disabled by default. There's a simple webview API call to enable JS before starting the webview. At this point, we can only reproduce this bug in browsers that do not execute JS.

More specifically, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.isscriptenabled(v=vs.92).aspx on how to enable JS.

Comment: OK, sorry for my mistake. It works now, with the isScriptEnabled=true.
Thanks a lot guys !

Comment: I got all things back to normal today. I wonder if there is a way that I can be in touch of modifications in Google code like that one. It will permit me to control that my app is still working and react quicker in case of any problem.

Comment: We do have a place where we often pre-release for testing purposes. Not every change goes there first, but often major ones do. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/google-auth-sandbox

Comment: Actually, the main place for communicating w/ Google on OAuth questions is: right here at StackOverflow! Google is now sponsoring the google-oauth tag and is using the forum above only for general announcements of incoming changes.

Answer (score 0):

We've identified an issue with our server that we hope to fix soon for the way we report an error when JS is not enabled on the client.

Clients that do not have javascript enabled will not be able to submit the OAuth approval form going forward. The error you're seeing, with the 302 to the 404 is a redirect bug in our error page that explains this requirement.

In addition, we have tested windows phone 7 IE on our page and recreated your issue. At this point we assume is related to JS in the client. We're looking into this and hope to have a fix soon.

Comment: I added all the URI during the process of login and auth.
I changed the redirect URL in the first request, it didn't changed anything.